# Allow for template argument deduction of type of member pointed to by pointer to member argument of method

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member, template-argument-deduction

I have made the following method as a little experiment to find out if this would be possible:

```
template<typename dataT>
class DemographicNode
{
    //...
    template<typename varT>
    varT count(const varT dataT::* variable = &dataT::citizens) const {
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

This works as expected except for the fact that this doesn't allow for template argument deduction of `varT` even though a call to this method would provide all the compile-time available information required.

Is there any way to enable template argument deduction in this case?

I am using VC++17.

**Edit:**
I have to call it in the following way:

```
gameState.getCountries()[0]->getDemoGraphics().count<double>();
```

and I want to call it with something like this:

```
gameState.getCountries()[0]->getDemoGraphics().count();
```

Comment: How do you call it?

Comment: Could you show the calling part? I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: Template argument deduction doesn't work with default arguments.

Comment: Just overload `count()` and call `count(&dataT::citizens)` inside.

Comment: @VTT Nope, because it's a pointer to member variable. You're not accessing the value after all, just getting a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, template argument deduction does not work with default arguments.

Here you can simply set a default template parameter for `varT`:

```
template<typename varT = decltype(dataT::citizens)>
varT count(const varT dataT::* variable = &dataT::citizens) const {

};
```

---

Or you can add an overload without parameters for `count()`:

```
template<typename dataT>
class DemographicNode {
public:
    // no more default argument here
    template<typename varT>
    varT count(const varT dataT::* variable) const {
    };

    // overload without parameters
    auto count() const {
        return count(&dataT::citizens);
    }
};
```